# clusters, heatmap and getting info from clusters by R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, heatmap

I've started recently using R to cluster my data. My purpose is to have a heatmap with the related dendrogram and to identify on the heatmap the clusters by squares. 
So far I tried `hclust` from `gplots` package and I could draw rectangles on the dendrogram with the code below:

```
a <-read.table ("test.txt", header = TRUE)
b <- as.dist(a)
dend <- hclust(b, method = "complete")
plot(dend)
groups <- cutree(dend, k=3)
rect.hclust(dend, k=3, border = "green")
```

My test.txt file look like this:

```
      a     b     c     d     e     f
a     1   0.1   0.9   0.5  0.65   0.9
b   0.1     1  0.39  0.83  0.47  0.63
c   0.9  0.39     1  0.42  0.56  0.84
d   0.5  0.83  0.42     1  0.95  0.43
e  0.65  0.47  0.56  0.95     1  0.14
f   0.9  0.63  0.84  0.43  0.14     1
```

I tried this code that works to obtain a dendrogram and the related clusters.
 [image: Dedrogram with rectangles from test.txt data.]

What I really want is something similar but with the heatmap. I would like the heatmap with squares around the clusters and the lists of the members of the different clusters. The heatmap should look like this:

As I work with large data (a 5200 x 700 matrix), I need a way to save the lists of members from each cluster.
I tried also `pheatmap` from the `pheatmap` package but I'm not sure about clustering and I cannot have rectangles around clusters.

I'll be very happy to welcome suggestions and comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?  I created the rectangle by hand, and you may be looking for R to do so, and for the three clusters above.

```
data <- read.table(file = "clipboard") # copied your test.txt file from above
data.m <- melt(data)
ggplot(data.m, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=value)) + geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low="red", high="green") +
  annotate("rect", xmin = min(as.integer(data.m$variable)), xmax = max(as.integer(data.m$variable)),
           ymin = .01, ymax = .2, fill = "transparent", col="black", lwd=2)
```

[image: heatmap with rectangle]

Comment: Thank you lawyeR...May be this other question I posted can elucidate what I want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28051493/heatmap-2-how-to-set-colsidecolors-with-clusters-by-r

Comment: Ah, that other question is quite different in terms of combining the heat map and the dendogram.  Well, maybe consider at least upvoting my answer if it helped you move in the direction you wanted.